# Output of matrix in FortranForm

Tags: matrix, fortran

```
matr2 = Table[FortranForm[matr[[i, j]]], {i, 4}, {j, 6}]
```

but i want output to be more like this

`matrix(1,1)=a11` output in Fortranform

`matrix(1,2)=a12`  output in Fortranform

`matrix(1,3)=` same way

that is i want elements to be assigned to some matrix variable and output to be shown in line by line (one element in one line).

output to be shown like 
`matrix(1,1)=` output in fortranform

because i want to use output in Fortran code, so i want to display output with matrix variable so that i can copy paste data from here and use matrix variable in fortran code. so please any help regarding this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `Export` to export to a file directly. Or use `CopyToClipboard` :

```
matr = RandomReal[{10^-12, 10^-6}, {4, 6}];
matr2 = Table[FortranForm[matr[[i, j]]], {i, 4}, {j, 6}];
matr3 = ExportString[
  Flatten@Table[
    "matrix(" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j] <> ") = " <> 
     ToString[matr2[[i, j]]], {i, Length[matr2]}, {j, 
     Length[matr2[[1]]]}], "Table"]
CopyToClipboard[matr3]
```

Comment: i have matrix

and i have shown the output in fortranForm.

but due to large characters in elements of matrix, when i copied the data into fortran Code, it does not take copied data because of line exceeding characters 2048.

so i have to put "& operator" operator in Fortran Form output.....how to do that? please help

Comment: http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Write2/

Answer (score 2):

Change rows and columns to taste.

```
rows = 2;
columns = 3;

matr = RandomReal[{10^-12, 10^-6},
   {rows, columns}];

(matr2 = Table[Row[{
       "matrix(", i, ",", j, ") = ", FortranForm[matr[[i, j]]]}],
     {i, Length[matr]},
     {j, Length[matr[[1]]]}] //
    Flatten) // Column
```

[image]

Comment: in The above output, suppose matrix(1,1)=output is very long characters. so in Fortrancode there is need of continuation character in that output after specified no. of characters. this difficulty how to overcome?? please help

Comment: You've posted this question at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/insert-a-linebreak-and-character-repeatedly-into-a-matrix-output-which-is-in-for  Look for answers there.