# How to show output of a matrix in m(1,1)=a11 m(1,2)=a12 ...in this way......i have 50 *50 size matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran

How to show output of a matrix  in m(1,1)=a11 m(1,2)=a12 ...in this way......i have 50 *50 size matrix

so i want to do it efficiently.

output to be shown like

m(1,1)=a11 (in fortranForm)
m(1,2)=a12 (In fortranform)
....
....continue in this way, one element per one line.

i have specific reason of doing this. i will copy paste my data into Fortran code to use it this data in less time.

please help me with this

Comment: You mean like this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6dtFh.png)  `Array[a, {5, 5}]`? Question not clear. What is the context?  ps. I just saw your other question here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65148/output-of-matrix-in-fortranform   is this different?

Comment: Hii.....No other question is also same.   i just want my matrix output to be shown like this   matrix(1,1)=a11 element in fortran form       matrix(1,2)=a12 element in fortranform....continue in this way

Answer (score 2):

There is no subtlety to this, but it works:

```
Table[i j, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
MapIndexed[Print["a(", #2[[1]], "," , #2[[2]], ") = ", #1] &, %, {2}];
```

Comment: What is `%102`?

Comment: @Nasser leftovers my own evaluation. Removed. :P

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense :), I thought you were using some new symbol/command in V10 but could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

building on @rcollyer's answer:
The main improvement here is we print the list of elements in a way that the whole list can be copied at once.  (also handle arbitrary dimensions automatically )

```
 SetAttributes[fortranprint, HoldFirst]
 fortranprint[array_Symbol] := 
      fortranprint[array, SymbolName[Unevaluated[array]]];
 fortranprint[array_, name_] :=
      Print@StringJoin@Riffle[ Flatten@MapIndexed[ StringJoin@
          {"        ", (* leading spaces for fixed format fortran *)
           name,
          "(", Riffle[ (ToString /@ #2) , "," ], ")=",
           ToString[FortranForm[#]]} & , array, {-1}] , "\n"];

 b = {{1.432, 2. 10^30}, {0, 1}};
 fortranprint[b];
```

> ```
>    b(1,1)=1.432
>    b(1,2)=2.e30
>    b(2,1)=0
>    b(2,2)=1
> ```

```
 fortranprint[{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}}}, "g"];
```

> ```
>     g(1,1,1)=1
>     g(1,1,2)=2
>     g(1,2,1)=3
>     g(1,2,2)=4
>     g(2,1,1)=5
>     g(2,1,2)=6
> ```

Comment: Yeah, mine was quick and dirty. I should have done this. +1