# Insert a linebreak and character repeatedly into a matrix output which is in fortranForm

Tags: matrix, string-manipulation, fortran

Suppose I have a very long string which is a11 element of matrix

a11=2*g*o*p*s*v-2*B*g*o*p*s*v*w+2*a*c*g*m*o*p*s*v+2*c*g*m*o*p*s*v*B-2*a*c*g*m*o*p*s*v*B+3*g*m*o*p*s*v*B-3*B*g*m*o*p*s*v*w*B+m*w**2*B +5*a*c*g*m***2 +op*s*v*B -a*c*m**2*w**2*B +c*g*m**2*o*p*s*v*B* - 3*a*c*g*m*o*p*s*v*+c*m**2-w**2*B-a*c*m**2-w**2*B....)

etc that goes on for almost 1000 lines. When exported to a .txt file, the file is >100MB. I want to use the expression in Fortan and Fortan will not accept lines greater than 100 characters or so.

To the string x, is it possible to insert a linebreak every 100 characters and insert  && at the end of each line and at the beginning of the next line?

i want to do it over the full matrix.
it is like first i want to convert matrix elements into FortranForm along with showing them with linebreak character

Comment: Yes. E.g. : http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Write2/

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

There's special function for generating fortran-like forms:

```
SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> 100]
FortranForm[string]
```

And certainly you can manage string manually. To insert new strings in the string you can write something like this:

```
string = StringJoin[ToString /@ Range[1000]];

step = 10
StringInsert[string, "&&\n&&", Range[step, StringLength@string, step]]
```

Comment: Dear Funnypony,   my problem is i have a matrix=[a11 a12 a13;a21 a22 a23; so on]   i want to show output to be in this format matrix(1,1)=a11 matrix=a12 ...which should be in fortranForm along with continutation character in output at 100 or 200 characters. thers should be "&" operator after say 100 or 200 characters.